# Python. Как сделать проверку текста на смайлики?

Tags: python

Например:
text = input("Введите текст:")
И как сделать так что бы, если в text есть смайлик, то сказать об этом? Если делать в ручную то это займет много времени, т.к. смайликов ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `if any(смайлик in text for смайлик in смайлики):`.

Comment: Посмотри таблицу ASCII, там первые коды - смайлы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36217640/7485582

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать так (на скорую руку):

Инсталлировать [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/).

```
import emoji

text = input('Введите текст ')

if ":" in emoji.demojize(text):
    print("Yes")
```

В окно для ввода помещаем например - Python is  -, вывод Yes.

Многое зависит от того, как именно приходят смайлики.